# Number of elements of order 2 in $D_n/Z(D_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, quotient-group

This exercise in supplimentry exercises for chapter 9 to 11 of contemporary Abstract algebra book by Gallian

> Let $n=2m$, where $m$ is odd. How many elements of order $2$ does the
> group $D_n/Z(D_n)$ have?

> Answer of this exercise given ( in "selected answer" section) is: $m$
> elements

Author used the notation $D_n$  (everywhere in book) to represent Dihedral group of order $2n$. But **according to me, if we use this notation(by author) then given answer is wrong!**

(According to me, if we use the notation $D_{2m}$ for Dihedral group of order $2m$ then answer is true! **that is** we consider the group $D_{2m}$ Dihedral group of order $2m$; where $m$ is odd  then number of elements of order $2$ in $D_{2m}/Z(D_{2m})$ is $m$ is true! )

Is, am I correct? Please help.

Comment: I hate that $|D_n|=n$ is even a possibility people have to consider. It leads to so much confusion, like here (seems the author confused themselves). Why can't we all just agree that $D_n$ (at least for $n\geq3$) should act on $n$ elements the way $S_n$ and $A_n$ do, and thus $|D_n|=2n$?

Comment: @Arthur, completely agrees with you.

Comment: @Akash Patalwanshi please check my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No  , you are wrong.

In both case , answer will be same , i.e, there are $m$ elements of order $2$ in $D_{n}/Z(D_n)$

Edit : If $|D_n|=2n $ and $n=2m$, where $m$ is odd.

Then , it is true that there are $m$ elements of order $2$ in $D_n/Z(D_n)$.

Because,
$D_{n}/Z(D_n) \cong D_m $ $\text{(here, $|D_m|=2m$)}$

(How? , Clearly $Z(D_n)=\{1,r^m\}$
where , $D_n=\{1,r,r^2,\cdot\cdot\cdot,r^{2m-1},s,sr,sr^{2},\cdot\cdot\cdot,sr^{2m-1}\}$

Then , $1Z(D_n)=\{1,r^m\}=r^{m} Z(D_n)$
$rZ(D_n)=\{r,r^{m+1}\}=r^{m+1} Z(D_n)$

$\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$

$\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$

$r^{m-1}Z(D_n)=\{r^{m-1},r^{2m-1}\}=r^{2m-1} Z(D_n)$

Similarly,
$sZ(D_n)=\{s,sr^{m}\}=sr^{m+1} Z(D_n)$

$\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$

$\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot$

$sr^{m-1}Z(D_n)=\{sr^{m-1},sr^{2m-1}\}=sr^{2m-1} Z(D_n)$

So, $D_{n}/Z(D_n)= \{Z(D_n),rZ(D_n),\cdot\cdot\cdot,r^{m-1}Z(D_n),sZ(D_n),srZ(D_n),\cdot\cdot\cdot,sr^{m-1}Z(D_n)\} \cong D_m $)

If $|D_n|=n $ and $n=2m$, where $m$ is odd.

Then $Z(D_n)$ is always trivial, so, $D_n/Z(D_n) \cong D_n$ , and there are $m$ reflection symmetries in $m-$ gon.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.

Comment: I don't understand how $D_4$ is a counterexample in the first part of your answer because $m = 2$ is not odd.

Comment: @Zoe H yeah you're right, I have edited.

Answer (score 0):

n=2m and m is odd, here Z(D_n) consists of two elements that is {R_0,R_180} and since m is odd then no other elements such R_90,R_270 can exist in Z(D_n)
And since the reflection are distinct then the no of elements of order 2 is just n/3=m.